# Encrypting files with GnuPG in a batch file does not work if ran as scheduled task

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, gnupg, pgp

I have a batch file that works fine when I double-click on it but not when I schedule it in Scheduled Tasks. I did some research and I believe it's because the variable is not being set when run within the Scheduled Task program.

```
 CD C:\PGP_Out

 Set FileToEncryp=
 FOR %%a in (list_*.txt) do set FileToEncrypt=%%a
 gpg --recipient "FTPTARGET" --output "%FileToEncrypt%.pgp" --encrypt "%FileToEncrypt%"

 CD \Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com /script=ftp.txt

 Exit
```

Comment: Is the task ran using the same user account you developed the batch script with? GnuPG uses per-account keyrings. In doubt, try running `gpg --import` at the beginning of your batch script.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I created the key ring as myself so I had to set my account in Scheduled Tasks as the Run As account.  Once I did that everything worked.

Comment: I added the comment again as a slightly extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

GnuPG uses per-account keyrings, make sure you run the scheduled task from the same user account used for developing the batch script or import the required keys in the account used for scheduling. You might also want to set the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable, but be aware GnuPG is very picky on appropriate access privileges.

In doubt, run `gpg --import` at the beginning of your batch script on each invocation to make sure the required keys are available.